# Changing state of object nested in array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

As stated in the title I'm trying to change the state of an object nested in an array of objects.  I just can not get this to work.  I've added a sample of what I'm trying to do in a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nameless-paper-udioo?file=/src/togglebutton.js:3949-4163).

I'm using a Material-UI component call ToggleButton (link to demo [ToggleButton](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-xnb72?file=/demo.js:510-531)).  I want to change the state to toggle the buttons in the group.  I was able to get this working for a create  function but can not get it working for my update function.

Trying to change the values of the object in the array is just not working for me.  Below are some things I've tried to no success. I want to change the `IsTrue:` so I can toggle the button to display the users selection.

```
        setAppetizer(true);            
        setRecipeObjectState({
            ...recipeObjectState,
            Category: [
                ...recipeObjectState.Category,
                {
                    IsTrue: appetizer,
                    category: "Appetizer",
                },
            ],
        });
```

This just adds more buttons to my button group.

```
        setAppetizer(true);            
        setRecipeObjectState((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            Category: [
                {
                    IsTrue: appetizer,
                    category: "Appetizer",
                },
            ],
        }));
```

I'm just lost now at this point.  I just want to also state that this is my first React project that is not just a sandbox for learning the framework and I'm also a jr. developer trying to learn.  I have search stackoverflow and nothing has helped me out.  I hope I have included enough information for someone to help out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your state and app appear to be *very convoluted*, but the general idea when updating nested array state is to shallowly copy the state at each level where an update is being made. Use array::map to map the `Category` property to a new array object reference and when the category matches toggle the `IsTrue` "selected" property.

```
setRecipeObjectState((prevState) => ({
  ...prevState,
  Category: prevState.Category.map((category) =>
    category.category === newCategory // <-- newCategory value from toggled button
      ? {
          ...category,
          IsTrue: !category.IsTrue
        }
      : category
  )
}));
```

Since your "selected" calculation is `selected={Boolean(item.IsTrue)}` you'll want to ensure your `IsTrue` element values are *actually* togglable, i.e. just store the boolean value right in the array.

```
const recipeObject = {
  AuthorId: authorId,
  BookAuthor: bookAuthor,
  BookTitle: bookTitle,
  Calories: parseInt(calories),
  Category: [
    {
      IsTrue: false,
      category: "Appetizer"
    },
    {
      IsTrue: false,
      category: "Breakfast"
    },
    {
      IsTrue: false,
      category: "Soup / Salad"
    },
    {
      IsTrue: false,
      category: "Vegetarian"
    },
    {
      IsTrue: true,
      category: "Meat (Beef, Pork, Chicken)"
    },
    {
      IsTrue: false,
      category: "Fish"
    },
    {
      IsTrue: false,
      category: "Dessert"
    }
  ],
  Description: description,
  DurationInMinCook: parseInt(durationInMinCook),
  DurationInMinPrep: parseInt(durationInMinPrep),
  ImageUrl: imageUrl,
  Ingredients: addedIngredients, // array
  Instructions: addedInstructions, // array
  IsRecipe: true,
  Likes: 0,
  RecipeId: selectedRecipeId,
  ServingSize: parseInt(servingSize),
  Title: title,
  YouTubeUrl: youTubeUrl
};
```

[image: Edit changing-state-of-object-nested-in-array-of-objects]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!.  The explanation was great!  I know my app looks convoluted.  It is.  Things kind of got out of control and I need to refactor it.  I have been meaning to try and find myself a mentor to help me out/bounce ideas off of and help to develop better development skills.

Answer (score 0):

You mutating the same reference, you need to render a copy or the component won't render (shallow comparison):

Try updating state like this.

```
const oldState = recipeObjectState;
oldState.Category = [
        {
          IsTrue: appetizer,
          category: "Appetizer"
        }
      ];

setRecipeObjectState(oldState);
```

Answer (score 0):

*I didn't try your component because it's huge.*

Updating a single object property in an array of objects seems to be a very common  use-case. Here is generally how you do that. Suppose `id` is a unique identifier of each object and that we want to toggle `selected`:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import faker from "faker";

const array = [];
for (let id = 1; id < 10; id++) {
  array.push({
    id,
    name: faker.name.firstName(),
    age: faker.random.number(100),
    selected: false
  });
}

export default function App() {
  const [list, setList] = useState(array);

  const onClick = (id) => (event) => {
    setList((list) =>
      list.map((item) =>
        item.id === id ? { ...item, selected: !item.selected } : item
      )
    );
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      Click on a item:
      <ul>
        {list.map(({ id, name, age, selected }) => (
          <li key={id} onClick={onClick(id)} className="item">
            {name} {age}
            {selected ? " ✅" : null}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-river-9sq6g?file=/src/App.js:0-825